# Can I make laravel collection as a model? or other ways to make `a model of collection`?

Tags: laravel, collections, model

I currently using laravel 5.8. Is there a way that make `Illuminate\Support\Collection` object as a model? The goal is to create a model that works also as a collection and there will be polymorphic relations on that model. I can't get a clear pictures for it.

Just before writing this question, I tried extends model class itself and stores a collection inside. That feels somewhat clumsy while manipulates collection items. What should I do if I want my model works same as collection?

---

**Edit A - Actual Problem**

Obviously, the question is inappropriate in some way. What I'm actually trying to do is storing lists. The list contains several model-extended objects and other list objects like below.

```
$parentCollection = [
    1,
    2,
    childCollection = [ 3a, 3b, 3c, collection3d = [], ... ],
    , ...
]
```

I have to deal with nested collection and collection itself. Storing it, loads it.. kind of things.

---

**Edit B - Nested Collection of itself**

Thanks to comments. I see that nest collection itself is already solved one from your comment. When I try this, at first, I make a classes named `Type`, `Test` which they are extension of `Model` class and it wraps `Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection`. Those two `Type`, `Test` has polymorphic relation with its entity class `CollectionItem`.

This way immediately cause two problem. (1) I cannot manipulate collection data directly at `Type` class. (2) If I want to my `Type`, `Test` would have other `Type`, `Test` or possible other polymorphic related collections, how is that I cannot figure.

Forgive my poor explanation. English was not my language so always hard to write what I think is kind of hard work.

Comment: Model always return collection

Comment: IMHO seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please can you explain your real original needs, the data you need to store or anything like that. It seems that you have already found a solution if a Collection could be a Model but they are two different objects. As posted the question has no meaning for anyone apart yourself.

Comment: I appreciate you edited your question, but it's still a bit too vague. The problem you have is already solved with a Relational Database: nested collections are simply what Laravel call relationships between Models/tables, you can read here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a view in your DB and making a model for it like a normal table.

You would need to use this settings in model:

```
protected $table = 'name_of_view';
```

To create a view in a migration use something like this:

```
// up method
DB::raw('create or replace view name_of_view ....');

// down method
DB::raw('drop if exists view name_of_view ...');
```

Comment: Thanks for checking, No I have suggested an out of the box idea that would achieve what I believe that he is wanting which is a model that returns a combination of information from different models